# Идентификация незарегистрированных пользователей при использовании DbSession в Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Очень странная проблема. Дело в том, что пару месяцев назад у меня возникла ситуация, что при использовании DbSession мне нужно было идентифицировать незарегистрированных пользователей с помощью обычной сессии (чтобы администратор мог зайти в админку), проблема не решалась до тех пор, пока я не добавил в настройки компонента `session` использование куки `'useCookies' => true`. На данный момент перестало работать даже с использованием куки. Не исключено что могло сломаться из-за изменения каких-то конфигураций в приложении (например изменение версии php 7.0 на 7.1). Любые варианты и догадки подойдут, так как на данный момент даже не знаю в какую сторону копать. Очень нужна помощь.

Вот конфигурации моего DbSession:

```
    'session' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\DbSession',
        'useCookies' => true,
        'timeout' => 60 * 60, // 1 hour
        'writeCallback' => function ($session) {
            // <удаляю повторяющиеся записи>

            return [
                'user_ip' => Yii::$app->request->userIP,
                'user_id' => Yii::$app->user->id,
                'last_write' => time(),
            ];
        },
    ],
```

[Вот мой предыдущий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/833858/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-dbsession-%D0%B2-yii2), при желании ознакомится более детально.

Comment: Так надо задебажить. Посмотреть факт добавления записи в БД и факт сохранения файла куки у пользователя в браузере. На всякий случай еще раз перечитать раздел документации и проверить как настроено приложение.

Comment: @fedornabilkin добавление записи в БД есть, куки добавляется. Просто из-за того что пользователь не идентифицирован, запись и кука перезаписываются и данные в сессии теряются.

Comment: А почему же он не идентифицирован? Приходит юзер на сайт, сервер генерит код и сохраняет в БД (или в файл), затем шлет куку в браузер, по которой может найти сгенеренный код. Если кука не соответствует записи, значит либо они разные, либо время жизни куки малое.

Comment: @fedornabilkin смотрите, все записывается когда нужно, но как только происходит редирект, данные не распознаются и перезаписываются. Предположим при использовании DbSession не используется обычная сессия, как мне проверить в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Думаю надо попробовать без БД, попробовать разные настройки куки (время жизни, домен, валидация).

Comment: @fedornabilkin я как только отключаю DbSession все работает как нужно. Но мне DbSession нужна для других целей, поэтому хочу понять как с ней подружится.